# Is there a free Halo 2 trial to download?

Tags: halo-2

Umm, just wondering this. I mean, there is a free version of Halo 1 Trial, so is there a free Halo 2 Trial?

Though I'm not that bored of Halo 1 Trial, I just want something new to do.

Please tell me if there is a free version, or have any information about it.

Answer (score 4):

### No.

Google will tell you this pretty quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are willing to buy the game or settle with the trailer (or playing on somebody else's disc), there is no way to play Halo 2, sadly. I have extensively tried to find it on all the websites out there. Sorry.